# Conversion to string in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Consider:

```
$ProfilePath = "HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows NT\currentversion\profilelist"
$ProfileList = ls -path $ProfilePath
foreach ($guid in $ProfileList)
{
    $gpath = $guid -replace "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE","HKLM:"
    $userpath = Get-ItemProperty -path "$gpath" | select ProfileImagePath
    $SUserName = [system.string]::$userpath
    $username = $userpath -replace "ProfileImagePath=C:\\Users\\",""
}
```

Currently `$userpath = @{ProfileImagePath=C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService`. I need to get it to a string so that I can do a comparison. How can I get this to convert to a string?

My attempt for `$SUserName` generates either a `blank` or `null string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the paths as strings with this:

```
$ProfilePath = "HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows NT\currentversion\profilelist\*"
Get-ItemProperty $ProfilePath | foreach {$_.ProfileImagePath}
```

Or use split-path to extract just the user name

```
Get-ItemProperty $ProfilePath | foreach {Split-Path $_.ProfileImagePath -Leaf}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don´t understand your question.

But I think you are looking for this:

```
$userpath.ProfileImagePath
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $key = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*'
 $key1 = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name ProfileImagePath).ProfileImagePath
```